# Ida python No module named tempo

Tags: ida, idapython, python

I tried to run [tempo.py](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/debugging/misc/tempo.py) from ida python github , but I got error `No module named tempo`

According to Igor Skochinsky answer  , this script is wrong

> Apparently, tempo was an internal module used during IDAPython
>   development. This sample should not have been released and will be
>   removed.

I want to dump the registers and dump the memory of the process like they did in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `tempo` was an internal module used during IDAPython development. This sample should not have been released and will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, not I got error `tempo has no attribute 'getregs'` on this line `L = tempo.getregs()`

Comment: @paramikoooo sorry, I was wrong, see update

Comment: that strange, this example should work, no? so how can I implement that with the tools I have in Ida Python?

Comment: Implement what? Maybe you should ask what you actually need

Comment: dump the register, and dump the memory of process. I update my post. thanks